how to use npmauthenticate step within azure dev-ops pipeline and not invalidate docker cache
I'm building a dockerized angular project using CICD from azure-devops. In my pipeline, I have:

dependencies that are installed from npm and some that are via artifact feeds within azure.

I have added the required .npmrc file at the root of my project and this all works ok.


Within my pipeline, I'm using the npmAuthenticate step to grant authenticated access to the private registry. This step in turn appends a generated access token within .npmrc file.
 - task: npmAuthenticate@0
   inputs:
     workingFile: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/.npmrc
     feed: 'xxx-xx-xxx'

As the whole build process is within docker, when it comes to copying over the .npmrc file, this is invalidating the docker cache, as the file has changes within it.
FROM docker.io/node:lts-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
COPY .npmrc .npmrc //cache invalidates from this point

RUN npm install
COPY . ./

RUN npm run build:project-x

Is there anyway to achieve authenticated access with the .npmrc file without invalidating the cache? I want my future builds to get quicker and utilise cache node_modules.

The npmAuthenticate@0 will append a generated access token into.npmrc file, which is designed behavior.
If you don't want the change on .npmrc file, you can go to DevOps target feed -> Connect to feed -> npm -> Other page, follow the step to set the .npmrc file(doc here).

Copy the authentication code on the page directly to your .npmrc file, user level .npmrc is not needed. Replace your email in the file.

; begin auth token
....
; end auth token


Generate the Base64 encoding based on the Personal access token on your local machine, copy and replace for [BASE64_ENCODED_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN] in your devops .npmrc above. (make sure your account has related permission, eg: owner or contributor permisson on the target feed)

My .npmrc file for your reference:

You can remove npmAuthenticate@0 task, as it can directly use npm install command in pipeline now.


thanks @wade this did in-fact solve the issue of the cache invalidating.
So for this i have marked as solved.
However i'm now left thinking this is not best practice to have auth tokens saved within my codebase.
i've subsequently looked into creating this .npmrcon the fly at build time, injecting the registry url and required tokens in the shape of arguments... keeping these away from code repo, and stored as pipeline variables.
But as per the npmAuthenticate@0 task, its also invalidates the cache as the meta data for the .npmrc file is different to the stored reference.

Thanks @user27873934. If you would like to build the .npmrc during the pipeline, you can append the token via command "printf "\n%s\n" "//pkgs.dev.azure.com/.../registry/:_authToken=$(system.accesstoken)" >> .npmrc" . then you can execute "npm install...". If you have any issue with the command, you can raise a new ticket, and i will follow up. :)

thanks @wade for following up. The above direction is what we ended up doing. Its just a frustration that that layer invalidates the docker cache.
I think what we will end up doing is creating a base docker image every time we have fresh dependencies. Then tag that docker image and pick it up and extend it with each build.
So this way we kind of keep our cached node_modules, just via a different route...now just need to work that process out.
IDK, all this drama to save ~1-2mins for each build
